# Pushing view controller is not working properly in ios

Tags: ios, storyboard

I am passing textfield data  between two view controllers. i have two view controllers Firstviewcontroller, Secondviewcontroller. i have embed them in navigation but when i click the button on first view controller, second view controller is not showing only black screen is showing.below is my code.

First view controller.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "secondViewController.h"

@interface FirstViewController : UIViewController<SecondViewControllerDelegate>

@property(nonatomic) secondViewController *secondview;
- (IBAction)btnclick:(id)sender;

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *textfield1;

@end
```

First view controller.m

```
- (IBAction)btnclick:(id)sender {
    secondViewController *SecondViewController= [[secondViewController alloc]init];
    SecondViewController.data=self.textfield1.text;
     [self.navigationController pushViewController:SecondViewController animated:YES];

}
- (void)dataFromController:(NSString *)data
{
    [self.textfield1 setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",data]];

}
```

Seconviewcontroller.h

```
@protocol SecondViewControllerDelegate <NSObject>

@required
- (void)dataFromController:(NSString *)data;

@end
@interface secondViewController : UIViewController
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *data;
@property(nonatomic,weak)id<SecondViewControllerDelegate> _delegate;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *textfield2;

@end
```

Seconviewcontroller.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.textfield2.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",_data];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}
```

whats the reason ??

Comment: Please also note your typo. SecondViewController.data should be  secondViewController.data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to either use storyboard and let it intanciate the view controller for you:

```
[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"SecondViewController"]
```

Or you can use xib files and tell the view controller which one to load:

```
[[SecondViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SecondViewController" bundle:nil]
```

Answer (score 0):

> second view controller is not showing only black screen is showing

Typically, this means that the view controller has no view. Your code does not explain where `secondViewController` is expected to get its view from. Is there a *secondViewController.xib*? If there is, is it correctly configured with a `view` outlet? If not, what does this view controller do in order to get its view?

Note that you have done a very odd thing with capitalization: you have given your class a small letter (`secondViewController`), while your instance has a capital latter (`SecondViewController`). This is backwards and a big mistake, and you should correct it immediately. Perhaps the problem is just a capitalization problem; if you call your class `secondViewController` and your xib file `SecondViewController`, that is not a match and they won't find each other.

Comment: And if you don't understand how view controllers get their views, you might want to read my explanation here: http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch19.html#_view_controller_and_view_creation

Answer (score 0):

I see "IBOutlet" in your code, it means you created the user interface of secondviewcontroller on storyboard. I guess [[secondViewController alloc]init] does not get UI element from storyboard then the black screen is shown. You have to create instance of secondViewController by loading from storyboard file.

Basically:

- you can get storyboard via storyboard file name
- on storyboard, Secondviewcontroller has an storyboard id which is set in  **Identity Inspector** and you can use it to get instance of Secondviewcontroller

You can refer this link for more detail
[loading iOS viewcontroller from storyboard](http://brainwashinc.com/2014/01/08/loading-ios-viewcontroller-in-code-from-a-storyboard-file/)
Hope this can help!